# PHP directory list question?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone help me with this,I'm stuck.Dont know why this dont work

```
$myPath = get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/uploads/'; // this is full path

function ReadDirList($d){
    $dir = opendir($d);
    $fs = "";
    while($folder = readdir($dir))
    {
        //if(is_dir($folder)){
            $fs = $fs. '<option>'.$folder.'</option>';
        //}
    }
    closedir($dir);
    echo $fs;
}
```

I call this function `<select> <?php ReadDirList($myPath); ?> </select>`
tnx in advance.

Comment: How, exactly, does it fail? When asking for help, always state the behavior you expect and the behavior you get, including any error messages.

Comment: Sorry,I'm kind a new here.It prints empty string,like $fs is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the function reference, `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` is going to be returning a URL.  If you want to access the local file system, you need a real filepath, not a URL.

Try this for the first line:

```
$myPath = WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/'; // this is full path
```

`WP_CONTENT_DIR` is defined in the config file, and should point to the `wp-content` folder of your installation.

Comment: tnx,it works,I didn't know that I need a real filepath.thank you very much.